# Which Azure service is needed for running exe file [Unity + Prime[31] WP8.1 Azure Plugin]

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, windows-phone-8.1, prime31

I am new to Microsoft Azure and wonder which services should I use to achieve the goal.

Briefly, I have Unity and Prime[31] Azure Plugin, and I want to send to the server a *.txt file. The executable (on the server) will then execute the .txt file and return another .txt file. This file will then received by Unity via the plugin.

Please let me know if there is anything not clear enough. English is not my native language though.

Thanks first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Azure Mobile Services. To know more about Azure Mobile Services, visit here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/services/mobile-services/

You can send any file from AMS(Azure Mobile Service) but you have to program your service (which is hosted on Microsoft Azure) to store/process according to your  requirement, you can use JavaScript and .Net language for server side scripting. 
Or Simply, you can add a database table to your AMS and insert the data into the table, that would be best.